# Count number of possibilities to split a string into X parts with at least 1 vowel

Tags: string, algorithm, substring

You are given a text (max 100 characters) required to split the word into X parts, each will contain minimum 1 vowel.

X is given in the input.

For example, for the following text: bcaeiouxtz and x = 3, we have 6 possibilities:

bca eio uxtz

bca ei ouxtz

bca e iouxtz

bcae io uxtz

bcae i ouxtz

bcaei o uxtz

I would like to write dynamic programming approach in which I will be able to count how many possibilities I can have.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A combinatorial solution exists as well. But dynamic programming should be fine, too. However, you have to be more specific with the question. What help, specifically, do you seek?

Comment: So you basically get a string a and an integer x in input. The question you want to answer is in how many ways can you split the string into x parts so there is at least one vowel in each part. The parts need to be non-empty substrings of s.

Comment: Can you add whatever approach you've tried so far? Show that you've potentially made an effort to solve the problem?

Comment: I tried solving it for x = 2 and number of vowels <=3 . The solution for x = 2 is easy, you just have to see if you can divide any string into two and query if each part has a vowel, this can be done using prefix sums. For number of vowels = 1, there is no solution. For vowels = 2, you have to see how many letters are there between the first and last vowel. And for vowels = 3, you have to multiply the amount of letters between the first and second vowel, times the amount of letters between the second and last vowel. This is what I got currently.